# How to install a gem to the current folder

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I want to use a Ruby gem locally (not install it for the entire machine) for use in a single script. I know how to install gems with Bundler with a Gemfile and `bundle install`. But for a simple script, this seems overkill to set up bundler.

Is there a way to install a gem to a subfolder of my script and use it, similar to the way npm installs Node.js packages in `node_modules`?

Here's what I have tried so far.

`gem install -i ruby plist` installs the `plist` gem in `ruby/gems/plist-3.1.0`

I tried to require it in my script `extract.rb` by doing `require './ruby/gems/plist-3.1.0/lib/plist` but that fails with `require: cannot load such file: plist/generator` (`plist/generator.rb` is required by `lib/plist.rb`).

Ruby 2.0 on OSX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to involve Bundler, just install your gems locally as in your example and then set the GEM_PATH env in your script before your require, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ROOT = File.expand_path('..', __FILE__)
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = File.join(ROOT, 'ruby')
# or to just append to
# ENV['GEM_PATH'] += ":#{ File.join(ROOT, 'ruby') }"

require 'plist'
```

assuming your script is in the same folder as the `ruby` folder (otherwise adjust the filepath accordingly).

Comment: The key was knowing that GEM_PATH influences where gems get loaded from.

Answer (score 6):

You can bundle install to a different location with the `--path` option, for example:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Also see http://bundler.io/v1.1/bundle_install.html

Comment: How would I load the gem from the script?

Comment: Just set up bundler with your project as described on their page, do a normal require and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating gemset for particular application. follow these steps for that -

```
$ rvm gemset create <gemset_name>
```

It will create a gemset for currently selected ruby version.
you can check currently selected ruby version by this command -

```
$ rvm list
```

Then navigate to your app directory by cd into it.

now execute this command -

```
$ rvm use @<gemset_name>
```

Now whenever you install any gem it will be installed in current gemset which is being used not for the entire machine.

Make sure - you run `gem install bundler` in newly created gemset so it will not raise error when you will run `bundle install`.